# How do I take a json POST and search for a user_id by username?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

When I pass the JSON Parameters: `{"friend"=>{"username"=>"example"}, "auth_token"=>"n2A1Sk85MZSupXEiE1nG"}`, I get the following error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: username)
```

---

```
FriendsController
def create
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @friend = Friend.new(params[:friend])
    @friend.user_id = current_user.id
    @friend.friend_id = User.find(user.username)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @friend.save
            #flash[:notice] = 'Game was successfully created.'
            #format.html { redirect_to(@game) }
            format.json  { render :json => @friend }
        else
            #format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.json  { render :json => @friend.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

---

```
Friend Model
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id
     belongs_to :user
     validates_presence_of :friend_id
     validates_presence_of :user_id
end
```

---

```
User Model
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
 # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable

 before_save :ensure_authentication_token

 # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :friends_attributes, :friends
 # attr_accessible :title, :body

 has_many :games#, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :friends, :dependent => :destroy

 validates_presence_of :username
 validates_uniqueness_of :username
end
```

---

How can I accept a username from JSON and then in turn find the corresponding `user_id`?  I am trying to allow a user to friend another by searching for the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `username` to the list of attributes that are accessible on the `Friend` model. So change:

```
attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id
```

to

```
attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id, :username
```

I believe that should do it.

Comment: I tried that and I got a different error: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: username):
  app/controllers/api/friends_controller.rb:26:in `new'
  app/controllers/api/friends_controller.rb:26:in `create'

Comment: That's because your `Friend` model doesn't have a `username`, your `User` model does. This is a separate problem from what you asked about here. (For the record, I think you've got your models a bit mixed up: friends should also be users, they don't need their own class.)

Comment: That is true, but what I wanted to do, was to have a list of users (all which can be friend-ed by another user).  The Friends model was strictly to make the relationship between two users (ie tying user 1 to user 2 by their ids).  Usernames I had stored in just the user model to avoid redundancies.  If this is not the best way to do this, what do you recommend?

Comment: Then what you want to do is replace the `Friend` model by a `Friendship` model, which will link your friends together. Inside the `Friendship` model add a line `belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"`. Then in your `User` model, replace the `has_many :friends ...` line with `has_many :friends, :through => :friendships`. See this ASCIIcast for details: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do.  Thanks for the help, I will implement that later.